# How to do stringify when there's quotation in exp with LPC macro?

Tags: c, macros

Currently I'm using LPC, which uses the same preprocessor as C.
We have a macro as below:

```
#define UT_TRUE(exp) _UT_TRUE(exp, "##exp")
```

But now we have an exp as:

```
UT_TRUE(map["true"])
```

so it becomes:

```
_UT_TRUE(map["true"], "map["true"]")
```

The exp becomes "map[" true "]" and true is left undefined.

Is there any tricks to fix the problem?

Comment: How can it become `_UT_TRUE(map["true"], "map["true"]")` when there's no macro replacement performed in a string like `"##exp"`? Is this actually what your C preprocessor outputs? Are you sure your macros are as you wrote them here?

Comment: Yes, this is the output. Did you mean there was no macro replacement because of the double quote?

Comment: Exactly. There is no macro replacement within string literals in C89 and later. And note that `##` is the token pasting operator, not the stringifyer (`#`).

Comment: You're right, I've tried it with gcc -E, and string in double quote will appear as original. So I need to figure out in LPC way now. Thanks

Comment: searching with "C" and "stringify" gives me interesting results. Did you try that? Voting to close the question.

Comment: First, you need to use single #, not ##. ## is for concatenation.

Comment: besides, C does not have `dictionary` data type support, like python. so `map["true"]` would not evaluate to anything useful.

Comment: The questions in text and in the body are different! Correct it!

Answer (score 4):

Try this, hope this helps,..

```
#define UT_TRUE(exp) _UT_TRUE(exp, #exp)
```

You can refer..

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: Thanks, actually this is a macro for unittest. The first one is expression and the other is the exp in string. I need to print it out so I double quote it.

Comment: @spin6lock, so this here exactly what you need, stringification of the macro argument.